# one node of a cluster does not show up in Ganglia web portal

Tags: ganglia

In Ganglia, I have configured a 2 clusters. cluster A has 2 nodes, cluster B has 13 nodes respectively. cluster B works well, while cluster A only has 1 node shown. The other node has exactly the same gmond.conf file, which is shown below:

```
globals {                    
  daemonize = yes              
  setuid = yes             
  user = ganglia              
  debug_level = 0               
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472        
  mute = no             
  deaf = no             
  host_dmax = 0 /*secs */ 
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */ 
  gexec = no             
  send_metadata_interval = 0     
} 

cluster { 
  #name = "unspecified" 
  name = "rpt" 
  owner = "unspecified" 
  latlong = "unspecified" 
  url = "unspecified" 
} 

host { 
  location = "unspecified" 
} 

udp_send_channel { 
  #mcast_join = 239.2.11.71 
  host = qt-dw-master
  port = 8557 
  ttl = 1 
} 

/*
udp_recv_channel { 
  #mcast_join = 239.2.11.71 
  port = 8557 
  #bind = 239.2.11.71 
  #bind = qt-dw-master
} 
*/

tcp_accept_channel { 
  port = 8557
}
```

gmetad.conf on qt-dw-master is shown below:

```
data_source "rpt" 60 rpt0:8557 rpt1-db:8557
```

I have tried using multicasting, but does not work. I also want to find **log files** of gmond, but failed. Anyone can help on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are all gmond running in the cluster A? Use commond `service gmond status` to confirm it